How to change which language you're editing subtitles for in Subtitld?
I'm trying to edit subtitles with Subtitld from Flatpak. It opens the .mkv file correctly, but it's editing the first language available alphabetically (Arabic). How can I change it so it opens the English subtitles?

I don't see an option in the settings or anything on their website
